# How to implement an "augmented reality" feature detection on Android with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, augmented-reality, firefox-android, google-mobile-vision

I'm currently implementing a web-app with a button that opens the native "augmented reality"-view directly by clicking on a link. The link, as well as the feature detection for iOS is pretty straight-forward:

```js
function isARSupported() {
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    return a.relList.supports('ar');
}
```

However, I couldn't find a way on Android to check whether the browser/device supports AR or not.

Is there a way how to implement that feature detection for AR-support in Google and Firefox, on Android?

Comment: Yup looking for this as well.